Several squid proxies in one docker container
At the moment, I am running 128 proxy IPs in 128 containers, each with a different port for each IP.
version: '3.7'
services:
  squid-ip-xx.xx.xx.xx:
    image: ubuntu/squid
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./squid_conf/squid.conf-xx.xx.xx.xx:/etc/squid/squid.conf
      - ./passwd:/etc/squid/passwd
    network_mode: host
    container_name: squid-ip-xx.xx.xxx.xx-port
  squid-ip-xx.xx.xx.xx:
    image: ubuntu/squid
    ...

I want to run several IPs with one container so that I can choose the proxy to use during the connection. How can I achieve this?
login:pass@xx.xx.xxx.xx:port
